# Passing Parameters to AWS Glue Worklfow

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-glue, aws-sdk-java

Looking into AWS Glue Workflow for Automation of an ETL pipeline process.

I have defined some workflow parameters to define which customer to run this job for and would like to pass this as input to the Workflow.

[image: Workflow Properties Screenshot]

I am confused as to how I can override these default workflow parameters whilst starting a workflow execution from either the AWS CLI

```
aws glue start-workflow-run --name <Workflow Name>
```

Or via the AWS Java SDK.

```
final StartWorkflowRunRequest startWorkflowRunRequest = new StartWorkflowRunRequest();
startWorkflowRunRequest.withName("Workflow Name");

final StartWorkflowRunResult startWorkflowRunResult = awsGlue.startWorkflowRun(startWorkflowRunRequest);
final String runId = startWorkflowRunResult.getRunId();
```

I see that there is a `aws glue put-workflow-run-properties` where you can update these values once you have a workflow --run-id executing but hoping to set these at workflow trigger time?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems like this may not be possible? If so thinking could move to a Step Functions based approach.

Comment: Old question, but just in case this helps anyone, [it's now possible to pass --run-properties when starting a workflow run](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/glue/start-workflow-run.html).